# Responsive ModalDialog/ModelessDialog Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible the create modaldialog/modelessdialog that is always x% of the screen?
I know that I can set constat width and height like so, but I'd love to have it depending on the user screen

```
function Modalprompt(){
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  Logger.log(window.innerwidth);
      var htmlOutput =HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
      .setWidth(600)
      ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput,"Wpisywanie osób do rostera");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved from Apps Script as the available methods are only: `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`.

What you can do instead is to file a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker and provide all the necessary details [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Comment: Ah, I really wanted for there to be a way. I filled it on Issue Tracker, thanks for help.